# UWP InvalidCastException when using XAML databinding

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

Can anyone explain how XAML data binding expressions are evaluated? I have a control with a registered property, VisualState.

```
public CardStates VisualState
{
    get
    {
        return (CardStates)this.GetValue(VisualStateProperty);

    }
    set
    {
        this.SetValue(VisualStateProperty, value);
    }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty VisualStateProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("VisualStateProperty", typeof(CardStates), typeof(StateManager), new PropertyMetadata(null, (s, e) => { }));
```

In the xaml I attempt to bind a value to this property. State exists parent's DataContext object.

```
<local:CardControl  VisualState="{Binding State.Value}" />
```

The generated code in XamlTypeInfo.g.cs looks like this

```
private void set_4_CardControl_VisualState(object instance, object Value)
{
    var that = (global::MeetEric.UI.Controls.CardControl)instance;
    that.VisualState = (global::MeetEric.ViewModels.CardStates)Value;
}
```

This code throws an InvalidCastException because the value of Value is a Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.Binding object.

Am I missing something obvious to enable working with data bindings? Do I need some form of converter?

Comment: Looks like several errors; are you trying to create an attached property or a regular property?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `typeof(StateManager)` to `typeof(CardControl)`. (at DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached)

This argument requires the owner of the DependencyProperty.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you try to using Binding with a regular property.  In order for the binding to resolve to the right type, you need to be binding to a `DependencyProperty`.

As others have mentioned, your syntax is a bit off which is probably causing the problem here.

This error is certainly very cryptic.  I just hit it in my own project, but as soon as I changed my property to a dependency one, it worked perfect.